# Google Chrome does not launch java for a JNPL

Tags: java, google-chrome, jnlp

When I try to execute a JNPL from my browser Google Chrome is downloading a file (.jsp) but when I open it with a text editor it really is a jnpl in XML format.

But the same link in Mozilla Firefox is working great, it suggest me to open it with Java and everything goes perfect.

What am I missing? or is it a bug of Google Chrome?

Comment: Why don't you use the file extension `.jnlp` instead of `.jsp`? I get the same behavior as you describe in IE11, but that could be because I'm using Windows RT.

Comment: Remember to set the correct MIME-type.